# Tkinter Scrollbars with labels, canvas and frames

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I wanted to make a page where I have on the right some labels and on the left some other labels with their respective scrollbar. But I didn't managed to do it.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

canvasL = Canvas(root, bg='blue')
canvasL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

canvasR = Canvas(root, bg='blue')
canvasR.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="news")

frameL = Frame(canvasL, bg='red', width=1000)
frameL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

frameR = Frame(canvasR, bg='red')
frameR.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

frameL.grid_propagate(False)
frameR.grid_propagate(False)

S1 = Scrollbar(frameL, orient="vertical", command=canvasL.yview)
S1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="news")

S2 = Scrollbar(frameR, orient="vertical", command=canvasR.yview)
S2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="news")

canvasL.configure(yscrollcommand=S1.set)
canvasL.configure(scrollregion=canvasL.bbox("all"))

canvasR.configure(yscrollcommand=S2.set)
canvasR.configure(scrollregion=canvasR.bbox("all"))

canvasL.create_window((0, 0), anchor='nw', window=frameL)
canvasR.create_window((0, 0), anchor='nw', window=frameR)

for i in range(0, 40):
    labelName = Label(frameL, text="Name : " + str(i), bg='#F5F5F5')
    labelName.grid(row=i, column=0)
    labelName = Label(frameR, text="Name : " + str(i), bg='#F5F5F5')
    labelName.grid(row=i, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

If you test this code you will see that there is a problem. Can you help me please ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Check my answer:

**For `scroll widget` on `canvas` follow these steps:**

1. Create frame 1, this will hold canvas and scrollbar
2. Create frame 2 that will scroll on canvas, you can grid any widget on this frame
   but you need to create window using `canvas.create_window`.

### You can discuss extra question in comment.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x400+0+0')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

########################################################################
######## Left Side ####################################################
left_container = tk.Frame(root, bg='green')
left_container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=(0, 2))
left_container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
left_container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

left_canvas = tk.Canvas(left_container, bg='orange')
left_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

left_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(left_container, orient='vertical', command=left_canvas.yview)
left_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
left_canvas['yscrollcommand'] = left_scrollbar.set

left_canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
left_canvas.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

left_final_window = tk.Frame(left_canvas, bg='green')
left_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=left_final_window, anchor='nw', tags='expand1')
left_final_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

for i in range(1, 51):
    label = tk.Label(left_final_window, text=f'Manish Pushpam ({i})')
    label.grid(row=i-1, column=0, sticky='nsew', pady=(0, 2))


left_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: left_canvas.itemconfigure('expand1', width=event.width))
left_final_window.update_idletasks()
left_canvas.config(scrollregion=left_canvas.bbox('all'))
############### Scroll Using Mouse Wheel ###############
def scroll(event, widget):
    widget.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")


def final_scroll(event, widget, func):
    widget.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", func)


def stop_scroll(event, widget):
    widget.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")


left_canvas.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: final_scroll(event, left_canvas, lambda event: scroll(event, left_canvas)))
left_canvas.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: stop_scroll(event, left_canvas))
########################################################################
######## Right Side ####################################################
right_container = tk.Frame(root, bg='orange')
right_container.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
right_container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
right_container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

right_canvas = tk.Canvas(right_container, bg='red')
right_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

right_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(right_container, orient='vertical', command=right_canvas.yview)
right_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
right_canvas['yscrollcommand'] = right_scrollbar.set

right_canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
right_canvas.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

right_final_window = tk.Frame(right_canvas, bg='green')
right_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=right_final_window, anchor='nw', tags='expand')
right_final_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

for i in range(1, 51):
    label = tk.Label(right_final_window, text=f'Manish Pushpam ({i})')
    label.grid(row=i-1, column=0, sticky='nsew', pady=(0, 2))

right_canvas.bind_all('<Configure>', lambda event: right_canvas.itemconfigure('expand', width=event.width))
right_final_window.update_idletasks()
right_canvas.config(scrollregion=right_canvas.bbox('all'))

right_canvas.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: final_scroll(event, right_canvas, lambda event: scroll(event, right_canvas)))
right_canvas.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: stop_scroll(event, right_canvas))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your very interesting answer. But do you know how to center the frames on the center of their area ? And also how to allow the possibility to go down and go up with the scroll pad of a mouse ?

Comment: @Mo0nKizz ,Now you can check again, I have added for scroll using mouse wheel

Comment: You are a life saver !!! Thank you a lot ? 
But how do you know how to solve all my problems ? :)

Comment: In past I Was facing same problem, I read lots of documentation to solve my problem.

Comment: And do you know how to center the labels in the frame ?

Comment: you can use ipadx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218986/discussion-between-mo0nkizz-and-manish-pushpam).

Comment: @Mo0nKizz Now everything is working, You can try it.

Answer (score 3):

First you should not execute the following two lines:

```
frameL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
frameR.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
```

because you should not put widgets into canvas using `grid()` or `pack()` or `place()`.  And you have used `create_window(...)` later to put them into the canvas.

Second the parent of the two scrollbars should be `root` instead:

```
S1 = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvasL.yview)
S1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

S2 = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvasR.yview)
S2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="ns")
```

Also you should not execute the following two lines as well:

```
frameL.grid_propagate(False)
frameR.grid_propagate(False)
```

As they may make the two frames having zero height.

Finally, you have to call the following two lines after calling `root.update()`:

```
root.update()
canvasL.configure(scrollregion=canvasL.bbox("all"))
canvasR.configure(scrollregion=canvasR.bbox("all"))
```

But it is better to update `scrollregion` upon resize of the frame:

```
frameL.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvasL.config(scrollregion=canvasL.bbox('all')))
frameR.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvasR.config(scrollregion=canvasR.bbox('all')))
```

Below is a modified example based on yours:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

canvasL = Canvas(root, bg='blue', highlightthickness=0)
canvasL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

canvasR = Canvas(root, bg='blue', highlightthickness=0)
canvasR.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="news")

frameL = Frame(canvasL, bg='red', width=1000)
#frameL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

frameR = Frame(canvasR, bg='red')
#frameR.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

#frameL.grid_propagate(False)
#frameR.grid_propagate(False)

S1 = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvasL.yview)
S1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

S2 = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvasR.yview)
S2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="ns")

canvasL.configure(yscrollcommand=S1.set)
canvasR.configure(yscrollcommand=S2.set)

canvasL.create_window((0, 0), anchor='nw', window=frameL)
canvasR.create_window((0, 0), anchor='nw', window=frameR)

for i in range(0, 40):
    labelName = Label(frameL, text="Name : " + str(i), bg='#F5F5F5')
    labelName.grid(row=i, column=0)
    labelName = Label(frameR, text="Name : " + str(i), bg='#F5F5F5')
    labelName.grid(row=i, column=2)

root.update()
canvasL.configure(scrollregion=canvasL.bbox("all"))
canvasR.configure(scrollregion=canvasR.bbox("all"))

# better update scrollregion upon resize of frame
#frameL.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvasL.config(scrollregion=canvasL.bbox('all')))
#frameR.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvasR.config(scrollregion=canvasR.bbox('all')))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your very interesting answer.  But do you know how to center the frames on the center of their area ? And also how to allow the possibility to go down and go up with the scroll pad of a mouse ?