# Tkinter canvar scroll with mousewheel

Tags: tkinter, scroll, tkinter-canvas

I am creating 4 frames and canvas with a for loop and assigning each of them a different scrollbar, i wanted to add the scroll with the mouse wheel and the code i found works fine, but only if the mouse cursor is not overing the labels or other widgeds that might be inside the frame inside the canvas. This is the error that i get AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'yview_scroll'

```
    f_s = ['s_one', 's_two', 's_three', 's_four']
    f_o = ['f_one', 'f_two', 'f_three', 'f_four']
    self.f_c = ['c_one', 'c_two', 'c_three', 'c_four']
    self.f_f = ['fs_one', 'fs_two', 'fs_three', 'fs_four']

    def set_mousewheel(widget, command):
        widget.bind("<Enter>", lambda _: widget.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', command))
        widget.bind("<Leave>", lambda _: widget.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>'))

    for f in range(4):
        f_o[f] = Frame(self.f_bot, width=250, height=580, bg=self.bg)
        f_o[f].grid(row=1, column=f)
        f_o[f].grid_propagate(False)
        self.f_c[f] = Canvas(f_o[f], width=229, height=580, bg=self.bg)
        self.f_c[f].pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        f_s[f] = Scrollbar(f_o[f], orient=VERTICAL, command=self.f_c[f].yview, bg=self.bg)
        f_s[f].pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.f_c[f].configure(yscrollcommand=f_s[f].set)
        self.f_c[f].bind('<Configure>', lambda event: event.widget.configure(scrollregion=event.widget.bbox('all')))
        self.f_f[f] = Frame(self.f_c[f], bg=self.bg)
        self.f_c[f].create_window((0, 0), window=self.f_f[f], anchor='nw')
        self.f_c[f].bind("<Enter>", lambda event: event.widget.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: event.widget.yview_scroll(-1 * (event.delta // 120), "units")))
        self.f_c[f].bind("<Leave>", lambda event: event.widget.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>'))
```

the labels inside the final frames are created with a for loop as well

Comment: Overthink your second last line of your shared code, because it does exactly what you ask for and the error suggests exactly what is wrong. You also seem to misunderstand the use of bind_all.

Comment: still not finding a solution for it. i tried every possibile combination i could

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm currently not on a machine, but you could try: `self.f_f[f].bind('<MouseWheel>', lambda e: e.widget.master.yview_scroll(-1*(e.delta//120),"units"))`

Comment: your solution has a weird result, now the canvas part does not move and inside the frame it responds intermittently

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution following this thread: [Tkinter Scrollbars with labels, canvas and frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191477/tkinter-scrollbars-with-labels-canvas-and-frames)

```
    def scroll(widget, event):
        widget.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")

    def final_scroll(widget, func, *_):
        widget.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", func)

    def stop_scroll(widget, *_):
        widget.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")

    for f in range(4):
        f_o[f] = Frame(self.f_bot, width=250, height=bot_height, bg=self.bg)
        f_o[f].grid(row=1, column=f)
        f_o[f].grid_propagate(False)
        self.f_c[f] = Canvas(f_o[f], width=229, height=bot_height, bg=self.bg)
        self.f_c[f].pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        f_s[f] = Scrollbar(f_o[f], orient=VERTICAL, command=self.f_c[f].yview, bg=self.bg)
        f_s[f].pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.f_c[f].configure(yscrollcommand=f_s[f].set)
        self.f_c[f].bind('<Configure>', lambda event: event.widget.configure(scrollregion=event.widget.bbox('all')))
        self.f_f[f] = Frame(self.f_c[f], bg=self.bg)
        self.f_c[f].create_window((0, 0), window=self.f_f[f], anchor='nw')
        self.f_c[f].bind("<Enter>", lambda e: final_scroll(e.widget, lambda event: scroll(e.widget, event), e))
        self.f_c[f].bind("<Leave>", lambda e: stop_scroll(e.widget, e))
```